# parse object not found iOS 10

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, ios10

After updating to iOS 10 I would always get this object not found error whenever I try to update a PFObject on the parse heroku server. I have been researching and have tried out what many people have suggested turning on keychain sharing on capabilities. But, still no sign of working.

Some codes I'm using:

```
let publishQuery = PFQuery(className: "allPosts")
    publishQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectIdToPublish)
    publishQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                publishQuery.getObjectInBackground(withId: object.objectId!, block: { (objectToPublish, error) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        let postAcl = PFACL(user: PFUser.current()!)
                        postAcl.getPublicReadAccess = true
                        postAcl.getPublicWriteAccess = true
                        objectToPublish!.acl = postAcl

                        objectToPublish!["isItPublished"] = true

                        objectToPublish?.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) -> Void in

                            if error == nil {

                                self.publishedOrNot[((cellIndexPath as NSIndexPath?)?.row)!] = true

                                self.myTableView.reloadData()

                            } else {

                                self.displayAlert("Sth's wrong", message: "Please try again")

                                print(error)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting printed in the logs :

```
2016-10-22 19:10:39.740 Pufff[609:9898] [Error]: Object not found. (Code: 101, Version: 1.13.0)
Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "Object not found." UserInfo={code=101, 
error=Object not found., temporary=0, NSLocalizedDescription=Object not found.})
```

Comment: @MazelTov edited my question, pls tell me if any additional code should be added!

Comment: simply: your code doesnt make any sense!, longer explanation: why do you call findObjectsInBackground with the whereKey before that? This function will always return just one object. Just use the getObjectInBackground function... if it tells you it cant find the object by ID are you 100% sure it is there? Maybe you are using pointers and you have to access them differently